# How do I escape double colons in an RDoc comment?

Tags: ruby, rdoc

I have a method that looks like this:

```
##
# Opens a file.
#
# Raises:
# +ArgumentError+:: On invalid encoding.
# +Errno::ENOENT+:: On invalid file path.
#
```

Unfortunately the double colons in `Errno::ENOENT` is interpreted as the double colons of a labeled list, and the comment renders like this using `sdoc`:

[image: Screenshot]

Is there any way to escape the double colons? I tried `+Errno\:\:ENOENT+::` with identical results.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Unfortunately that renders as `+Errno%3A%3AENOENT+`

Comment: Ok, had that encoding in the back of my mind, apparently not remembering correctly :)